# Display of printing digits are blank

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a code from *Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction to the Python Language*:

```
    import sys


    Zero = ["  ***  "," *   * ","*     *","*     *","*     *"," *   * ","  ***  "]

    One = [" * ", "** ", " * ", " * ", " * ", " * ", "***"]

    Two = [" *** ", "*   *", "*  * ", "  *  ", " *   ", "*    ", "*****"]

    Three = [" *** ", "*   *", "    *", "  ** ", "    *", "*   *", " *** "]

    Four = ["   *  ", "  **  ", " * *  ", "*  *  ", "******", "   *  ",
    "   *  "]

    Five = ["*****", "*    ", "*    ", " *** ", "    *", "*   *", " *** "]

    Six = [" *** ", "*    ", "*    ", "**** ", "*   *", "*   *", " *** "]

    Seven = ["*****", "    *", "   * ", "  *  ", " *   ", "*    ", "*    "]

    Eight = [" *** ", "*   *", "*   *", " *** ", "*   *", "*   *", " *** "]

    Nine = [" ****", "*   *", "*   *", " ****", "    *", "    *", "    *"]

    Digits = [Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine]

    try:
        digits = sys.argv[0]
        row = 0
        while row < 7:
            line = ""
            column = 0
            while column < len(digits):
                number = int(digits[column])
                digit = Digits[number]
                line += digit[row] + "  "
                column += 1
            print(line)
            row += 1
    except IndexError:
        print("usage: bigdigits.py <number>")
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err, "in", digits)
```

When I run `bigdigits.py`, it shows this:

[image]

My Python version is 3.5.3.

Comment: You know you can run Python files other than by copy-pasting them a block at a time into the IDLE interpreter?

Comment: Also, you want `digits = sys.argv[1]`. Run the script from the command line, not from a REPL session, if you are trying to use `sys.argv`.

Comment: You may want to consider going to File>New File and then pasting the code there. It will give you a better idea of the indentation (which is off in this case), you can also run the code by hitting F5 on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand the code you are copying before blindly copy and pasting it.

The problem here is `digits = sys.argv[0]`. You also ignored the usage part `'usage: bigdigits.py <number>'`, the author apparently misunderstood `sys.argv`.

Running `python bigdigits.py {number}` -> `sys.argv` will be `['bigdigits.py', 'number']` -> Use `digits = sys.argv[1]` to actually retrieve the number from the command line argument. 
You have to give a command line argument to the program (a number) or change `digits = sys.argv[0]` to a string with a number in it, e.g. `digits = "1"`.

I don't have IDLE available, so I'm not sure what's used as `sys.argv[0]` and why it doesn't throw an error. You could print out `sys.argv[0]` to test this.

From the code example, the code in the book is really bad. The inner while (`while column < len(digits):`) is completely redundant for all digits < 10. The variable naming (capital case) is horrendous. The same goes for using different variables which only differ in case (`digits` and `Digits`). `for` would have been much nicer instead of `while`. If this example is to introduce the concept of `while`, it's a rather bad example. Just my 2cents.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can understand the code now!!! I found that sys.argv[0] is the script name of command line what user inputs. No wonder it can't work!